# Date Validation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation, date, calendar, popup

i have problem with date validation in javascript

the problem is i have popup calendar the return a date value 
i want to check the date in javascript before send it to parent page

in popup calendar.aspx

```
function passDateValue(DateValue)
{
    window.returnValue=DateValue;
    window.close();
    return false;
}
```

in popup calendar codebehind

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "SelectDate", "passDateValue('" + clrPopUp.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString() + "')", true);
```

the function that call the popup calendar and check the returned value

```
function Calendar_popup(tbClientID)
{  
   var today = new Date();

   var Day = today.getDate();

   var Month = today.getMonth()+1;

   var Year = today.getFullYear();

   if(Month<10){Month = '0'+Month;}

   if(Day<10){Day = '0'+Day;}

   var todayFormat = Day + "/" + Month + "/" + Year;

   datevalue = window.showModalDialog("Calendar_Dialog.aspx?ctlid=" +       tbClientID, '',"dialogHeight:250px;dialogWidth:300px;");

   var startdate = Date.parse(datevalue);

   var enddate = Date.parse(todayFormat);

   if (startdate>enddate)
   {alert('BirthDate Must be less than today');
   return;
   }
}
```

is there anyway to check date ?

thanks!

Comment: What is the format of the date you are expecting?

Comment: I have Used the ToShortDateString() method  its format date to :"dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693298/js-check-for-valid-date-format/28777878#28777878

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [date.js](http://datejs.com), specifically...

http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#compare

> Compares the first date to the second date and returns an number
>   indication of their relative values. -1 = this is < date. 0 =
>   values are equal. 1 = this is > date.

The [`isAfter()`](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#isAfter) and the [`isBefore()`](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#isBefore) methods might be useful for your problem :)

Download the library here:

http://code.google.com/p/datejs/downloads/detail?name=date.js&can=2&q=

Comment: thanks for this reference , but when i used Date.Compare() the debugger give Runtime error (Object doesn't support this property or method ) i dont know why

Comment: you have to import the library! download it, include it in your html, and then it should work