# Validate date in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Note that this seems like a question that is asked many times, but somehow I can't get the most common solution to work.
Most answers revolve around a solution like this one:

```
function isValidDate(){
  var dateString = '2001/24/33';
  return !isNaN(Date.parse(dateString));
}
```

In Firefox this returns a false as the result of that Date.parse is a number; 1041462000000.

How do I fix this..?

Comment: `return (Date.parse(dateString) > 0);` ?

Comment: I guess it's `isNaN()` not `isNan()`.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot right, but that was a typo and the problem in is in the parse part in my opinion

Comment: @Cobra_Fast but the number is already > 0 isn't it?

Comment: @Maarten yeah but if it fails, it will likely return `false` or `null` or some other value that would cause this test to fail.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast in my example I think it returns 1041462000000, or am I looking very wrong at the result of Date.parse('2001/24/33')?

Comment: @Maarten Correct, and `1041462000000` is larger than `0`, so it's a valid date.

Comment: true, but in my case, the inputted date invalid was overflown(?) into a future date, not what I wanted..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to do this is to create new date object based on the string and compare the result of that object with the input string. If it is not the same, the date was invalid and JS did a fallback to a closer (valid) date. Something like this:

```
function isValidDate(str){
   var split = str.split('/');
   var date = new Date(split[0], split[1]-1, split[2]);

   return (date.getFullYear() == split[0] && date.getMonth()+1 == split[1] && date.getDate() == split[2]);
}
```

call with:

```
var isValid = isValidDate('2001/24/33');
```

Note: in this case the input string is assumed to be in a specific format. If your sure that it's always the same format there is not problem. If not, your need the work some more on this code.

As a sidenote: Use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) if you need to do extensive date operations.

Comment: The problem with this is that the `Date` class accepts a few different formats for creation. So this will not work all the time.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast as I can format the date however I like, in my case transforming it from 'dd-mm-yyyy' to 'yyyy/mm/dd' before handling it, would Baszz' solution work in all browser?

Comment: @Maarten Yes, if you can be 100% sure of the input format, then it will work.

Comment: Check this for validating the date : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693298/js-check-for-valid-date-format/28777878#28777878

Comment: @ynos1234 why is that any better?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use http://www.datejs.com/.

Very cool library.