# Validate date range in javascript

Tags: javascript

Date format is in "mm/dd/yyyy". It is not giving me proper result. It is only validating month.

```
    <input type="text" name="durationstart" id="durationstart" value="">
     <input type="text" name="durationend" id="durationend" value="" onclick="return chk_val12()" >

        <script>
        function chk_val12()
        {
            var durationstart   =   document.getElementById('durationstart').value;
            var durationend =   document.getElementById('durationend').value;

            if(durationstart>durationend)   
            {
                alert("Please enter proper duration range");
                return false;
            }   
            else
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
        </script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693298/js-check-for-valid-date-format/28777878#28777878

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare validate date like this.

`Text box` contains the value of **`string`** dataType.  So what the below code does is

```
if(durationstart>durationend)   // Invalid
```

Instead  parse it to `date` object.

---

**Updates:**

Though it works, there are chances for browser compatibility  so here I have written the full date parsing

```
function chk_val12() {
    var durationstart = document.getElementById('durationstart').value;
    var durationend = document.getElementById('durationend').value;
    var st = durationstart.split("/");
    var en = durationend.split("/");
    var startDate = new Date(st[2], (+st[0] - 1), st[1]);                                          
    var endDate = new Date(en[2], (+en[0] - 1), en[1]);
    if (startDate > endDate) {
        alert("Please enter proper duration range");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/D2uDf/1/)

**FYI:** Make sure user enters the right date format.

What it does?

1) Split the dateString you have like

```
var st = durationstart.split("/");
```

2) Parse it like `new Date(YYYY, MM, DD)`

```
var startDate = new Date(st[2], (+st[0] - 1), st[1]);
```

Comment: How to parse it to date object?

Comment: You can simply do this `if(new Date(durationstart) > new Date(durationend))`, meanwhile I will update with my own parsing

Answer (score 1):

#### Extracting and comparing formatted date strings from text inputs

You'll need to use the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object's [`parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method to convert the input strings into milliseconds, then compare the 2:

```
var durationstart = Date.parse( document.getElementById('durationstart').value );
var durationend   = Date.parse( document.getElementById('durationend').value   );
```

This depends upon the input being entered in a way the `Date.parse` method expects though — in formats following either the `Wed, 3 Feb 2014` or `2014-02-03` standards.

#### Converting arbitrary formats into date objects

If the user is likely to use another input format, you may want to use a plugin such as [Sugar](http://sugarjs.com/dates) to parse a wider range of possible formats. Sugar adds a `Date.create( inputString )` method which accepts [the following formats](http://sugarjs.com/date_formats).

#### Using HTML5 @type=date inputs

An alternative for modern browsers is to use inputs of type [`date`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.date.html) instead of `text`, which would allow you to extract the date values directly without fear of the user entering an unparseable format. Using this method you would change the HTML to:

```
<input type="date" name="durationstart" id="durationstart" value="">
<input type="date" name="durationend" id="durationend" value="" onclick="return chk_val12()" >
```

…and use the native `valueAsDate` method to extract the values as follows:

```
var durationstart = document.getElementById('durationstart').valueAsDate;
var durationend   = document.getElementById('durationend').valueAsDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function dateCheck() {

    fDate = Date.parse(document.getElementById("durationstart").value);
    lDate = Date.parse(document.getElementById("durationend").value);

    if(fDate >lDate )   
        {
            alert("Please enter proper duration range");
            return false;
        }   
        else
        {
            return true;
        }

}
```